# SSRS report - Display 1 to Many relationships

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I am trying to build a custom SSRS report and publish to our CRM system. I have a Dataset created using FetchXml by connecting to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365. The data set has 1 to Many and Many to Many relationships. The query looks fine and I am able to preview the Dataset results in Visual Studio. I am able to display the primary entity fields in the report but failed to show the 1 to Many relationship values. Please suggest on how to get this wprking. My fetch xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
   <entity name="entity1">
      <attribute name="name"/>
      <link-entity name="entity2" from="entity2id" to="entity1id">
         <attribute name="name"/>
      </link-entity>
   </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Failed to show? Any error ?

Comment: How do you reference the entity2 name attribute in the report? You could introduce alias for the linked entity attribute to make it more "clear".
Also the link-entity element looks a bit fishy, as it joins entity2id to entity1id, which are most likely never equal.

Comment: No error, that area remains blank @ArunVinoth

Comment: I am just dragging and dropping the fields from the dataset on to the report. If I open the actual expression of the entity2 name, it shows =Fields!entity29bd2f473_name.Value where as the entity1 name shows =Fields!name.Value @Jonas Rapp

Comment: use fetchxml tester from xrmtoolbox to build the query & test or use advanced find..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alias` & `link-type` is missing in your query syntax.

```
<link-entity name="entity2" from="entity2id" to="entity1id" alias="xyz" link-type="inner" >
```

On a side note, I recommend you to use [Xrmtoolbox FetchXML builder](http://fxb.xrmtoolbox.com/) to build the query without errors.

Comment: Neither alias nor link-type is required for the query to execute. But it might be necessary to use alias for the reqoprt to be able to distinguish between entity1.name and entity2.name, either on the link-entity element or the attribute element of the linked entity.

Comment: Thank you both of you. @JonasRapp to your point, I added aliases at the link-entity level and I am now able to see values in the report. However, I only see the values of the first record. How do I loop through all the records and print them in the report? Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874860/can-you-write-a-single-fetchxml-query-to-get-1many-relationship